# How to get JDK environment variable on Mac

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

On macOS, I downloaded the Java 20 package from the official website. I can see the version output in the terminal by inputting `java -version` after installing the package. I can't get the JDK environment variables in the files like zshrc, bashrc, profile, etc.

Which file the JDK environment variable is set on and how can I check it?

Comment: I got it. 
I print

Comment: By the way, there is no one single “official website” to obtain a JDK. Several vendors offer JDK products including Microsoft, Amazon, BellSoft, Azul Systems, Oracle, Adoptium, SAP, Red Hat, IBM, and more. All of these JDK products implement the Java specifications, all are thoroughly tested. See [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b).

Answer (score 1):

I think I have got the answer.

1. After I input "which java" in terminal, I got the full path of "java" command is "/usr/bin/java".
2. Obviously, the reason why the java command can take effect is because there is a corresponding executable file in the /usr/bin directory.
3. "/usr/bin/java" is an actual program, not a symlink

reference:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149452/java-location-from-usr-bin-java
2. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269588/how-does-usr-bin-java-work-on-mac

Answer (score -1):

To set the JDK environment variables on macOS, follow these steps:

Open your terminal.

Check if you have a .zshrc file or a .bash_profile file in your home directory by running:

```
ls -a ~
```

This will list all files, including hidden ones. Look for `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile`.

If you're using Zsh, edit the `.zshrc` file. For Bash, edit the `.bash_profile` file. You can use a command-line editor like `nano` or a GUI editor like VSCode. For example, to edit .zshrc with nano, run:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Add the following lines at the end of the file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Replace `/path/to/your/jdk` with the actual path to your JDK installation.

Save the file and exit the editor (in `nano`, press `Ctrl + X`, then `Y` to confirm changes, and `Enter` to exit).

To apply the changes, either restart your terminal or run:

```
source ~/.zshrc   # For Zsh
```

For Bash:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now, your JDK environment variables should be set, and you should be able to use Java commands in your terminal. If you're unsure about the exact path where you installed the JDK, you can use the `which java` command to find it:

```
which java
```

Remember to replace `/path/to/your/jdk` with the actual installation path.

Comment: Do not edit your $PATH variable. Java wrappers are already on your path, and the correct response to `which java` is `/usr/bin/java`. Setting JAVA_HOME in there is fine, but don't add the JDK bin dir to your $PATH.